# How can I find the amount of duplicates an element has within a list?

Tags: python, list, count

In this code, I have a user-generated list of numbers and have to find the amount of duplicates a specific element has within that list. I am getting an error in the function. How do I fix this?

```
def count(list,y):
    new_list = []
    for j in range(0,x):
        if(list[j]==y):
            new_list.append(list[j])
        else:
            pass
    print(new_list)    
    length = len(new_list)
    print("The number {} appears {} times in the list".format(y,length))

        
list = []
x = int(input("Please enter the size of the list you want to create: "))
for i in range(0,x):
    value = input("Please enter value of list : ")
    list.append(value)
print("The list of the values you entered : {}".format(list))  
y = int(input("Which element do you want to find the number? : "))
count(list,y)
```

Comment: `if(list[i]==y)` should be `if(list[j]==y)` (And similarly on the following line.)

Comment: There are by the way much easier ways you could do this in any case - for example with `filter`, or a list comprehension.

Comment: You can shorten the full count function to a lambda function using list comprehension: `count = lambda arr,y: len([x for x in arr if x == y])`

Comment: You can simplify your life (or at least your program) by looking at the `Counter` object in the `collections` module.

Comment: Saying "getting an error in the function" is way too vague. Please [edit] your question and be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were multiple issues in your code.

In the loop in function count instead j you are using i as index.
initiation of loop index till range(0,x) => x is not defined as the variable is not assigned in this scope, instead use len of the list.
All the inputs added to the list were strings and the one that was searched was an integer.

Other suggestions:
do not use `list` as a variable name as it is a keyword.
Below this code I am also providing a shorter version of the function count.

```
def count(mylist,y):
    new_mylist = []
    for j in range(0,len(mylist)):
        print(mylist[j])
        if(mylist[j]==y):
            new_mylist.append(mylist[i])
        else:
            pass
    length = len(new_mylist)
    print("The number {} appears {} times in the mylist".format(y,length))


mylist = []
x = int(input("Please enter the size of the mylist you want to create: "))
for i in range(0,x):
    value = int(input("Please enter value of mylist : "))
    mylist.append(value)
print("The mylist of the values you entered : {}".format(mylist))
y = int(input("Which element do you want to find the number? : "))
count(mylist,y)
```

Shorter version

```
def count(mylist,y):
    length = mylist.count(y)
    print("The number {} appears {} times in the mylist".format(y,length))
```

Comment: Small mistake: "initiation of loop index till range(0,x) => x is not defined as the variable is not assigned in this scope" x was defined with `x = int(input("Please enter the size of the list you want to create: "))` in the original post

Comment: You said that it wasn't defined even thought it was.

Comment: I mentioned that 
x is not defined as the variable ```is not assigned in this scope```

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought you were talking about the for loop outside the function. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

one issue, you're trying to acces the i'th element in list, but i is not initialized. Try replacing i with j

```
    for j in range(0,x):
            if(list[i]==y):
                new_list.append(list[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind me taking liberties with your code, here's an example using the Counter from collections. Note that it doesn't do exactly the same thing as your code, as Counter doesn't use indexes as you were using before.

```
from collections import Counter

input_counter = Counter()
while True:
    value = input("Please enter a value (or nothing to finish): ")
    if value == '':
        break
    input_counter[value] += 1
print(input_counter)
y = input("Which number do you want to count the instances of? ")
print(input_counter[y])
```